# Pay Pal REST API "unsupported_grant_type"

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to get an access token from the Pay Pal REST API, following this article: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#get-an-access-token

My request looks like this:

```
POST https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
Accept: application/json 
Accept-Language: en_US 
Authorization: Basic [redacted] 
Host: paypal.com 
Content-Length: 31 
Expect: 100-continue 
Connection: Keep-Alive 

grant_type=client_credentials
```

But I keep getting `400 Bad Request` with the following response data:

```
{ “error”: “unsupported_grant_type”, “error_description”: “unsupported grant_type” }
```

I can't figure out why - as far as I can see, I've followed the instructions exactly!

Their "Merchant Techincal Support" has been absolutely no help.

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR;** PayPal REST API's GetAccessToken endpoint does **not** trim whitespace.

I solved it. The astute will notice the following discrepancy:

```
Content-Length: 31
...
grant_type=client_credentials
```

The data is only 29 characters - the extra two being `\r\n` carriage return and line feed.

In code (I'm using C#/.NET) this was a matter of changing:

```
writer.WriteLine("grant_type=client_credentials");
```

To

```
writer.Write("grant_type=client_credentials");
```

This corrected the issue.

Comment: The first sentence makes it seem that paypal is at fault here. I can highly recommend you use utilities to generate application/form-data instead of doing it yourself. As you've found, this hand-writing this is prone to errors.

Comment: This post is more about immortalising this (current) quirk of their API. I've seen many people asking about it across various technologies, and Pay Pal support was no help, so I've decided to note it down here.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Postman, add it to Params tab. Like so:

[image]